# Could not get authorization.basic working in laravel 5.2.7

Tags: oop, laravel, interface, laravel-5

I am getting following error while calling for authentication

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure, you `User` class extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` what is default in Laravel 5.2. This class implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` ant this contract is required in function `validateCredentials`:

Default User class for Laravel 5.2 can be found here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php

Comment: Thanks man.... I was stuck at this for hours. Dude can you suggest some good tutorials for RESTFUL API using Laravel apart from Laracasts